# Crystal Reports Selection Formula If No Match Then

Tags: crystal-reports

I currently have a Crystal Report with a selection formula that looks like this

```
{dbo.CustomerName}={?CustomerName}
 AND
{dbo.Opportunity}={?Opportunity}
```

An issue that I'm finding is that *sometimes* there isn't a matching customer name, but the report still needs ran on the subsequent selection formula. Is there a way to create an `IF THEN` statement that says something like:

```
IF IsNull({dbo.CustomerName}={?CustomerName})
 THEN
{dbo.Opportunity}={?Opportunity}
 ELSE
({dbo.CustomerName}={?CustomerName} AND {dbo.Opportunity}={?Opportunity})
```

Obviously the `IsNull` operator requires a field and not a statement, but I'm not sure how to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
(IsNull({dbo.CustomerName}) AND {dbo.Opportunity}={?Opportunity})
 OR
({dbo.CustomerName}={?CustomerName} AND {dbo.Opportunity}={?Opportunity})
```

Comment: This has continually frozen Crystal Reports for me and will not work. To expand upon what I said above.. The end user is prompted with two parameters: Customer Name & Opportunity. Because both of those parameters have fields within the report that rely on those parameters, if one parameter doesn't match a record, the report is blank. What I'm needing to accomplish is that if the Customer Name parameter doesn't match a customer record, go ahead and still run the report just based on the Opportunity parameter.